# How to callback on flyway migrate?

Tags: migration, data-migration, flyway

Considering flyway as a db version tool, but have a use case in mind which I've not seen discussed.

How does one manage a cache layer after a db migrate?  That is, if/when a migration happens, how can I notify an external tool to flush the cache (a memcached cluster, for example)?

More specifically, how can I tell hibernate that flyway has performed a migration, causing data/schema changes to the underlying db (so that I may manage the cache appropriately)?

Answer (score 0):

I can safely say RTFM is appropriate here! :)

The migrate() method returns in integer corresponding to the number of successful migrations...so, if

```
migrate() > 0
```

then do whatever I need to do some other way (trigger a cache flush, etc).

Thanks SO!  Sometimes the best answer is no answer. :)